# I Want get end substr

Tags: php, substring, substr

So this is my code: i want get agm from http://example.com?agm=12345 end substr agm to get 12

```
  echo $_GET["agm"] if substr(["agm"], 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the value of `agm` or just the...text? If it's just the text "agm", just write it out as a string...

```
$str = "agm";
echo $str; // agm
```

Otherwise, to get the contents of "agm"

```
$data = $_GET['agm'];
echo $data; // 12345
```

If that's not what you're after, I really haven't a clue what you're asking.

Comment: $data = $_GET['agm']; echo substr($data, 0, -3);

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of errors in your code.

```
echo $_GET["agm"] // you should end it with ;

if substr(["agm"], 0, -3);
```

You should:

1. Use parenthesis for a criterion, so `if(...)`
2. You should use `$_GET["agm"]` instead of `["agm"]`

You can use `substr($_GET["agm"],0,2)` to take first two characters.

Please refer to manual examples of [`substr()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Comment: It works, but you should assign it to a variable or echo, at least.